# Giving different permissions to two groups for a single directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Let me explain the situation, I have 15 users which are assigned to a bunch of different groups. I gave `rwx` permissions to all 15 but 2 users (I simply made a group specifically for that) for a directory `bills`, but theres another subdirectory `access`, in which I need to give `r-x` permissions to a group of 2 users, and `rwx` permissions to another group made up of 2 users as well. I will also need to do the same thing on different directories later on.

So, is this even possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Look up ACLs (`getfacl`/`setfacl`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign multiple groups to a single directory. For that you will want to use Access Control Lists (ACL) just like "muru" said above.
[tutorial on ACL](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-manage-acls-on-linux).
Here's another great tutorial by Benjamin Cane [Benjamin Cane - ACL tutorial](http://bencane.com/2012/05/27/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/).